# News about Salesforce Releases

Tags: release

Where can we see the upcoming Salesforce release dates and other details about those releases?

I tried to search in Google about any website which can tell about the upcoming release dates but couldn't find any. Please help!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to know when your org will be updated to a new release, you should start from [trust page](https://status.salesforce.com/current) then search for your instance name (i.e. eu16) or your custom domain, click on the link and open *Maintenance* tab.
That tab holds information about next scheduled release date:
[image: Maintenance]

Winter 24 will be released on October and Spring 24 on February.

You can see your instance name from Setup > Company Information

While to get the latest release notes you could simply [serach on help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/search-result?language=en_US#q=release%20notes&t=allResultsTab&sort=relevancy).

Moreover you could keep an eye on the [Salesforce Blog](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/) since usually they publish an article about the upcoming release.
Just searching for "[Dates Sandbox Preview](https://www.salesforce.com/search/#q=Save%20These%20Dates&sort=relevancy)" provides the articles for the previous releases.